# SimpleXML skipping CDATA in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

I'm using SimpleXML to convert an XML file. Like this.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('rt.xml',  null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
var_dump($json);
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

This works fine, but it's leaving out data that I need.

For example, looking at this section of the XML. I'll comment which data I get returned and which isn't:

```
<title>Something Here</title> //returned
        <link>https://example.com</link> //returned
        <pubDate>Fri, 24 Mar 2017 13:19:17 +0000</pubDate> //returned
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[bsmith]]></dc:creator> // not returned
        <guid isPermaLink="false">https://example.com</guid> //returned
        <description></description>
        <wp:post_id>54432</wp:post_id> //not returned
        <wp:post_date><![CDATA[2017-03-24 13:19:17]]></wp:post_date> //not returned
```

By `not returned` I mean that it isn't in the array created from the XML.

I've tried this as well, but that doesn't work either.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('rt.xml',  null);
$json = json_encode($xml);
var_dump($json);
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

How can I ensure that my array includes, for example, `wp:post_date`? In addition, I see that the fields I'm missing are CDATA except for `wp:post_id`. That's missing from my array, but isn't CDATA.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the common factor between the elements that are not returned? *They are all namespaced* (and nothing else is). The CDATA markers don't appear relevant.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, so how do I ensure they are included in my array?

Comment: @jonmrich — If I knew that, I'd have answered the question instead of making a comment.